# Микроглюки при движении камеры от первого лица в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет.
Есть код движения камеры от первого лица:

```
[SerializeField] private Camera cam;
private const float CAMERA_UPPER_CLAMP = -90f;
private const float CAMERA_LOWER_CLAMP = 54f;
private float sensitivity = 20f;
private float xRotation;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    Look();
}

private void Look()
{
    float mouseX = PlayerInput.Instance.GetLookingAxis().x * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = PlayerInput.Instance.GetLookingAxis().y * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, CAMERA_UPPER_CLAMP, CAMERA_LOWER_CLAMP);

    cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

И фрагмент кода, который возвращает Input камеры:

```
public Vector2 GetLookingAxis()
{
    return playerInputActions.OnFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}
```

Проблема в том, что игра работает нормально, высокий FPS (там нечему глючить), но бывает когда прокручиваешь камеру, происходит что-то вроде пропуска кадра, и она глюком движется чуть дальше чем ты её двинул.

Сюда пишу с мыслью, если ошибка в коде, или есть люди с похожим опытом, которые поделятся тем, что помогло им.

Ниже прикрепляю билд, если хотите лицезреть как это конкретно происходит:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pJXV_Uvn1qQUxS49tPv4oiRn0eTEnvPS?usp=sharing